# How to make a website like cambly using wordpress

Tags: wordpress, web

I need to make a website just like cambly using word-press not from scratch any advice please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must use html5 video plugins to make live broadcast.maybe there are some plugins for this job.html5 is most popular live video broadcast technology in todays.it doesnt need any extention installation while flash needs it.also every browser evenmore mobile browsers support html5 live broadcasting techonology.if you know development you can do it easyly.you must know html5,css,php,mysql and wordpress theme and plugin development.

if you want save the live broadcast on your web server, you must that mkv needs less size but mkv doesnt supported wide browser scala.to solve this problem, you must use mp4 file type.but you must notice that mp4 file size is huge than other file sizes.

you can use ffmpeg technology to make all of them video transformings.

but you must know a thing that if you want use ffmpeg technology, probably you must use linux vps server.because many hosting company doesnt support this technology in shared hostings.

so, if you want to sell this website as a plugin or theme, probably you can not because your customers must install your item on vps server also need to install ffmpeg techonology.

please give up point to my answer

Comment: thank you for your answer Faruk, What I meant is not the video only I mean the structure of the website with minuets booking and how meetings are subtracted from the whole plan that the students buy.

Comment: for appointment, you can use "easy appointment" plugin, also you can use "user registration plugin" for new user feature

Comment: @ImadHasan why you dont look at themeforest.com? maybe you can find a good theme